# Multithreading order of actions on GUI

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am currently coding a program that downloads multiple csv-Files from different servers using WGET. Every download is a new thread because I call WGET as a process using the WaitForExit(10000) method, so WGET has 10s time to download. If the download did not finish within that time, the thread is killed because the server didn't answer in time.

Also, there is a listview that logs what my program is doing at the moment and which thread has ended with which status.

So that is my method to log (lvw_log is my ListView):

```
Public Delegate Sub LogDelegate(ByVal Text As String)

Public Sub Log(Text As String)
    If lvw_Log.InvokeRequired Then
        lvw_Log.BeginInvoke(New LogDelegate(AddressOf Log), New Object() {Text})
    Else
        lvw_Log.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + ": " + Text)
        lvw_Log.TopIndex = lvw_Log.Items.Count - 1
        lvw_Log.Refresh()
    End If

End Sub
```

The delegate is called when text has to be added to my ListView from one of the WGET-Threads. 'p' is an object of an own class to hand over a set of variables accesible for the thread.

I store every thread in an ArrayList called WGETThreadArray:

```
Dim WGETThreadArray As New ArrayList

For i = 0 to NumberOfFilesToDownload - 1
  Dim WGETThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf StartWGET)

  WGETThreadArray.Add(WGETThread)
  Log("Starting thread " + i.ToString)
  WGETThreadArray(i).Start(p)
Next
```

Now I want to wait for all threads to finish or to be aborted:

```
Log("Waiting for threads to finish")
For i = 0 To WGETThreadArray.Count - 1

  WGETThreadArray(i).Join()

Next
    Log("All threads closed")
    Log("Downloaded all DB-Info-Files")
```

The thread (method StartWGET) is this:

```
Public Sub StartWGET(p As Object) 
    'this method is called for each thread to parallely download the necessary files

    Dim procInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(p.PathToWgetExe, p.ArgumentString)
    procInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
    procInfo.UseShellExecute = True

    Dim WGETProcessHandler As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(procInfo)

    If Not WGETProcessHandler.WaitForExit(10000) Then         'if WGET doesn't finish within '10000' milliseconds, the thread gets killed

        WGETProcessHandler.Kill()
        Log("DB " + p.DBName + " was not loaded. Thread " + p.ThreadIndex.ToString + " killed ")
        DatabaseArray(p.ThreadIndex).isLoaded = False
        WGETThreadArray(p.ThreadIndex).Abort()

    Else
        DatabaseArray(p.ThreadIndex).isLoaded = True
        Log(p.URL + " downloaded. Thread " + p.ThreadIndex.ToString + " ended successfully.")

    End If
End Function
```

As you can see, the method "Log" is called within the threads. The problem is that the main thread always writes to the ListView before the other threads. So I see the line "All threads closed" before a message like "Thread ended successfully". Eventhough I used .Join() method in the for-Loop. I wanted to make it wait until all threads have finished.

So how can I make the main thread pause until all other WGET-Threads are done. And also, how can I make them log before the main thread takes over and tells me that all threads have finished.

I know it is hard to explain and I really hope I made myself clear. If not, please ask me again so I'll explain my self better.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you use Threads instead of e.g. Tasks which are way easier to handle?

Comment: I used threads because I didn't know any better to be honest. But why wouldn't this work with threads?

Comment: Use `Wait Handles`

Comment: I din´t say it won´t work with threads ;) checkout the answers. But Tasks have mighty methods [WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) and [WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) which seem to please your problem.

Comment: These comments are red herrings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) Tasks or Threads, Waits or Joins, these will not solve the actual problem because the UI thread is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The main thread is blocked by the Join() calls so the BeginInvoke of Log, which tries to switch to the main thread, has to wait for the main thread to become available (after all the joins) This means that the actual calls to Log will be executed AFTER the main thread becomes available. And that is after waiting for the threads and logging the "All threads closed" message

Call the waiting for the worker threads on a new thread to free up the main thread to do **just** UI rendering. This is an important principle: to have a responsive UI, have the main thread do only very little work and *never* block it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Log("Waiting for threads to finish")
 Dim SomeAlive as boolean
 do 
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    SomeAlive = False
    For i as integer = 0 To WGETThreadArray.Count - 1
       if WGETThreadArray(i).IsALive then 
           SomeALive = True
           Exit For
        end if
    Next
Loop While SomeAlive
```

YOur statement

```
 WGETThreadArray(p.ThreadIndex).Abort()
```

Is pointless since the thread will abort at the end of the routine anyway.

Also spawning multiple processes to download multiple files will probably NOT buy you much over doing them one at a time.